# Resumable and Validation on createWriteStream Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, google-cloud-storage, createwritestream

I've been using **Google cloud storage api** to upload some files.
I've run into some errors of **socket hang up** when using the request for the upload.

After searching a bit, I've came across [Error: socket hang up code: 'ECONNRESET' on Google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184088/error-socket-hang-up-code-econnreset-on-google-cloud-storage) which solved the issue using:

```
.createWriteStream({
      resumable: false,
      validation: false,
       ...
    }
```

I couldn't find any documentation about those parameters (**resumable** and **validation**) and why using them solved my issue.
How those parameters works on this context?

Comment: 1) Your code does not show the complete OS/Environment/API/Method/SDK Version that you are using/calling. 2) Make sure you have an **error** event handler to log the actual error. 3) I do not think setting **resumable** and **validation** fixed your problem. I think that covered up the actual problem. Cloud Storage could be too busy to handle your request at that instant (rare), there is a protocol problem or many other possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#:%7E:text=CreateWriteStreamOptions) for the Cloud Storage API for Node, the `resumable` property is used to force a [resumable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#introduction) upload. Resumable uploads are helpful to bypass connection errors when uploading objects to Cloud Storage buckets. In this context, the `resumable` property appears useful, since `ECONNRESET` errors include [connection timeouts](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#common-system-errors). As for the `validate` property, it is used to perform checksum validations.

I also noticed that the thread you linked does not use the provided `upload` method of the API, which, as per the docs, is a wrapper for `File.CreateWriteStream()` and is the method used to upload files as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs) and [related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556281/).